# How do I get the HTML code using luacurl / libcurl / curl and Lua

Tags: curl, lua

what am I missing in my code to be able to get the html source code of a website (credit to @Michal Kottman)?
The same as if you were to right-click and click "view page source" in chrome.

```
local curl = require "luacurl"
local c = curl.new()

function GET(url)
    c:setopt(curl.OPT_URL, url)
    c:setopt(curl.OPT_PROXY, "http://myproxy.bla.com:8080")
    c:setopt(curl.OPT_HTTPHEADER, "Connection: Keep-Alive", "Accept-Language: en-us")
    c:setopt(curl.OPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30 )
    local t = {} -- this will collect resulting chunks
    c:setopt(curl.OPT_WRITEFUNCTION, function (param, buf)
        table.insert(t, buf) -- store a chunk of data received
        return #buf
    end)
    c:setopt(curl.OPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, function(param, dltotal, dlnow)
        print('%', url, dltotal, dlnow) -- do your fancy reporting here
    end)
    c:setopt(curl.OPT_NOPROGRESS, false) -- use this to activate progress
    assert(c:perform())
    return table.concat(t) -- return the whole data as a string
end

--local s = GET 'http://www.lua.org/'
local s = GET 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dT_fkwX4fRM'
print(s)
file = io.open("text.html", "wb")
file:write(s)
file:close()
```

Unfortunately it must be using Lua and using luacurl binding for libcurl as luasocket it not working when provided a proxy (at least for me).
My downloaded file is empty. Using cmd I get the page source without problems
`curl http://mypage.com`

It works perfectly for lua.org but for youtube links it does not. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
local curl = require "luacurl"
local c = curl.new()

function GET(url)
    c:setopt(curl.OPT_URL, url)
    c:setopt(curl.OPT_PROXY, "http://myproxy.com:8080")
    c:setopt(curl.OPT_HTTPHEADER, "Connection: Keep-Alive", "Accept-Language: en-us")
    c:setopt(curl.OPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30 )
    c:setopt(curl.OPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true) -- REALLY IMPORTANT ELSE FAIL
    c:setopt(curl.OPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36")
    c:setopt(curl.OPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false) -- REALLY IMPORTANT ELSE NOTHING HAPPENS -.-
    c:setopt(curl.OPT_ENCODING, "utf8") -- could be important
    local t = {} -- this will collect resulting chunks
    c:setopt(curl.OPT_WRITEFUNCTION, function (param, buf)
        table.insert(t, buf) -- store a chunk of data received
        return #buf
    end)
    c:setopt(curl.OPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, function(param, dltotal, dlnow)
        print('%', url, dltotal, dlnow) -- do your fancy reporting here
    end)
    c:setopt(curl.OPT_NOPROGRESS, false) -- use this to activate progress
    assert(c:perform())
    return table.concat(t) -- return the whole data as a string
end
```